# Powershell - Create CSV from files(s) with non-conforming data

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 4K+ files that need to be converted into CSV files.
Each field needs to be extracted and then added to a CSV file in the order they are found.

I have a script that I'm hoping I can re-use for this purpose.  The script below will read the first line and examine it then process the remaining lines.

I altered the script to capture JUST the first string on the first line. That works.  I am able to capture "ADJMT-HIS-WK".
I now need to process the rest of the file.

As you can see the rest of the file consists of two numerics a column name and then more characters at the end of the line like this.

```
05 DTE-CALL               9(6)
```

I need to capture just column name (in this case for this line it's **DTE-CALL**) on every line.  The column name appears only once per line and it is always after the two numerics.
Once I have the data, I then have to output it into a CSV file consisting of all the fields I captured including the Table name from line one and all the column names from the rest of the file.
Each file may have at minimum a single occurrence of each or a single table name with hundreds of column names.

My output file needs to look like this

```
ADJMT-HIST-WK,SRVCG-OFC-CDE,ST-CDE-FMHA,CTY-DST-CDE,SRVCG-CDE-OFC-CTY,.,.,.,. and so on.
```

If I can wrap each field in quotes, that would save me a step later on.

Would anyone be able to simplify this procedure for me?

RAW Data

```
ADJMT-HIST-WK                            VER     1 D  SUFFIX

          05 SRVCG-OFC-CDE                                                     
          10 ST-CDE-FMHA                           9(2)                       
          10 CTY-DST-CDE                           9                          
          10 SRVCG-CDE-OFC-CTY                     9(2)                       
         05 DTE-CALL                               9(6)                       
         05 CR-AMT-ADJMT                           S9(9)V99                   
         05 DR-AMT-ADJMT                           S9(9)V99                   
         05 PROCG-STAT-INDCTR                      X(1)                       
         05 DTE-DPST                                                          
          10 MO-GRGRN                              9(2)                       
          10 DAY-GRGRN                             9(2)                       
          10 YR                                    9(2)                       
         05 REAS-CDE-CB                            X(3)                       
         05 USER-ID                                                           
          10 AUTHY-CDE-TRML-OPRTR                  X(1)
```

Script

```
$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\IDMS" -File -Recurse 
$regex = '^\S+'
ForEach ($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
  $firstLine, $remainingLines = $CBLFile | Get-Content
  if ($firstLine -cmatch $regex) {
      $toRemove = $Matches[0].Trim()
      Write-Host "Found Match - $toRemove " -foregroundcolor Red
 #   & { $firstLine -creplace $regex; $remainingLines -creplace $toRemove } |
 #     Set-Content -LiteralPath $CBLFile.FullName
  }
}
```

Comment: The expected output format doesn't make any sense unless all tables have the same number of columns - is that the case?

Comment: I need a list of column names PER file.  The input would be a file like above and the output would be a CSV file with the same name but an extension of .CSV
I have 4K+ files as input and I would have 4K+ CSV files as output

Comment: So you want a CSV file with corresponding headers, but no data, for each input file?

Comment: Each input file is unique.  Some could have just a table name with 1 column and others can have a table name with 5000 columns

Comment: Correct!  All I have and need are the headers.  There is no actual data.  These are Just Mainframe DB2 layouts that need to be ingested into a new system.
An Example of all I need extracted from each file is the table name from line 1 and the column names from the remaining lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exact same approach to extract the column names: use `-{c,i,}match` to test if the string has the relevant data, `$Matches` to extract.

You can use the `-f` string format operator to quote each name.

```
$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\IDMS" -File -Recurse 
$tableNameRegex = '^\S+'
$columnNameRegex = '^\s*\d{2}\s+(\S+)'

foreach ($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
  $firstLine, $remainingLines = $CBLFile | Get-Content
  if ($firstLine -match $tableNameRegex) {
    # extract table name, add quotes
    $tableName = '"{0}"' -f $Matches[0]

    # then do the same for all the columns names
    $columnNames = foreach($line in $remainingLines){
      if($line -match $columnNameRegex){
        # again, add quotes before outputting
        '"{0}"' -f $Matches[1]
      }
    }

    # concatenate all names with comma, write to disk
    @($tableName;$columnNames) -join ',' |Set-Content "$($CBLFile.BaseName).csv"
  }
}
```